# Why am I get a syntax error here when I am equating a variable containing an integer and a variable containing a numerical input from the user?

Tags: python, object

I am just learning the basics of Python and created a number guessing game. I want the user to be able to guess the number as many times as possible until they guess correctly. I did this through a while loop but the code, `"else guess == a:"` near the end is giving me a syntax error. I am confused because the while loop ensures that the input guess is an integer by the `if` statement,

```
if guess.isdigit():
     guess = int(guess)
```

Please help

```
import random 
a = random.randint(1,10)

print("this is a number guessing game")
question_one = input("Would you like to play? Yes or No?:")

if question_one == "Yes":
    print("Let's go!")
else:
    print("That sucks!")
    exit()
guess = None
while guess != a:
    guess = (input("Alright, guess a number from 1-10"))
    if guess.isdigit():
        guess = int(guess)

    if guess > a:
        guess = int(input("Guess lower!"))
    elif guess < a:
        guess = int(input("Guess higher!"))
    else guess == a:
        print("you got it!")
```

Comment: An `else` doesn't take a conditional. The `else` clause executes if none of your `if` or `elif` clauses produced a match.  See e.g. [these docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Comment: you can not use else with condition. you have to use elif guess == a: instead of else guess == a: .

Answer (score 0):

else doesn't let you define a condition. else will execute if all other conditionals return false. You should change that last `else` to `elif`. Or you can simply leave out the conditional `guess == a` all together. If it is not greater than or less than, the only other thing it can be is equal to.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the last else, the code inside the else will be executed if any other condition goes false. So I think if you change the last else with an elif we work properly.

Answer (score 0):

An **else** statement contains the block of code that executes if the conditional expression in all your **if** or **elif** statements is false. Hence in your case you're supposed to use the elif statement instead of else. See the following:

```
elif guess == a:
        print("you got it!")
```